# Биндинг для ListBox из CheckBox-ов

Tags: c#, wpf, binding

Подскажите,пожалуйста. Имеется ListBox, состоящий из CheckBox-ов,необходимо его забиндить со следующей коллекцией

```
    public class CheckPoints 
    {
        private readonly List<PointItem> _list;
        private readonly int _max;
        public CheckPoints(int max = 3)
        {
            _max = max < 1 ? 1 : max;
            _list = new(max);
        }
        public void Add(PointItem item)
        {
            if (_list.Contains(item)) return;
            if (_list.Count == _max )
                _list.RemoveAt(0);
            _list.Add(item);
        }

        public IEnumerable<PointItem> GetPoints() => _list;
        public void Delete(PointItem item)
        {
            _list.Remove(item);
        }
    }
```

..то есть необходимо при нажатом CheckBox-е добавлять элемент в коллекцию (или удалять соответственно), при этом идет отслеживание,чтобы кол-во элементов в коллекции было не более max.
Спасибо :3

Comment: Нужно больше конкретики с примерами. Пока кажется, что вы забрели не в ту степь и непонятно, как вас вернуть на верный путь. Какую именно задачу решаете? Скорее всего надо копать в сторону `CollectionView` с фильтром без создания лишней коллекции, а при использовании данных - просто фильтровать через Linq. А класс ваш больше похож на костыльную реализацию `HashSet<T>`.

Comment: Вообще еще можно правильно реализовать `INotifyCollectionChanged` + `INotifyPropertyChanged`. Только перечислитель нужно будет реализовать на самом классе а не свойством. Посмотрите на гитхабе как реализована `ObservableCollection<T>` в .NET, это сойдет как пример.